# Inserting the Characters at specific position of the file

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, character

I have a file that I made for my model input. But I has some missing characters. I want to insert these characters at their position that model can read its 
Its class i checked is that

```
file. class("outfile.txt")
[1] "character
```

So the file from my codes after different  codes is

```
HYDRUS_Version=5
WaterFlow=0
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=0
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=0
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=0
SubregionNumbers=0
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=120
ObservationNodes=160
GridVisible=160
SnapToGrid=160
ProfileWidth=160
LeftMargin=160
GridOrgX=160
GridOrgY=160
GridDX=160
GridDY=160
```

and my required file is  [I want to insert 4 characters in it, two `;` and `[Main]` are at the start and two  `;` and `[Profile]` are inside the file. I want the final file as given below.

```
;                           
[Main]                      `
HYDRUS_Version=5
WaterFlow=0
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=0
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=0
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=0
SubregionNumbers=0
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
;                                
[Profile]                        
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=120
ObservationNodes=160
GridVisible=160
SnapToGrid=160
ProfileWidth=160
LeftMargin=160
GridOrgX=160
GridOrgY=160
GridDX=160
GridDY=160
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:
     imported_text <- readLines("outfile.txt")

```
     [1] "HYDRUS_Version=5"        "WaterFlow=0"             "SoluteTransport=0"       "Unsatchem=0"             "Unsatchem=0"             "HP1=0"                  
  [7] "HeatTransport=0"         "EquilibriumAdsorption=0" "MobileImmobile=0"        "RootWaterUptake=0"       "RootGrowth=0"            "MaterialNumbers=0"      
 [13] "SubregionNumbers=0"      "SpaceUnit=cm"            "TimeUnit=days"           "PrintTimes=160"          "NumberOfSolutes=0"       "InitialCondition=1"     
[19] "NumberOfNodes=101"       "ProfileDepth=120"        "ObservationNodes=160"    "GridVisible=160"         "SnapToGrid=160"          "ProfileWidth=160"       
[25] "LeftMargin=160"          "GridOrgX=160"            "GridOrgY=160"            "GridDX=160"              "GridDY=160"
```

and try the `c` function:

```
 imported_text2 <- c(";                            `here I want this`","[Main]                       `here I want this`",imported_text)
```

Furthermore you can do: select the

```
final_text <- c(imported_text2[1:20],";                                `here I want this`","[Profile]                        `here I want this`",imported_text2[21:length(imported_text2)])

[1] ";                            `here I want this`"     "[Main]                       `here I want this`"     "HYDRUS_Version=5"                                   
 [4] "WaterFlow=0"                                         "SoluteTransport=0"                                   "Unsatchem=0"                                        
 [7] "Unsatchem=0"                                         "HP1=0"                                               "HeatTransport=0"                                    
[10] "EquilibriumAdsorption=0"                             "MobileImmobile=0"                                    "RootWaterUptake=0"                                  
[13] "RootGrowth=0"                                        "MaterialNumbers=0"                                   "SubregionNumbers=0"                                 
[16] "SpaceUnit=cm"                                        "TimeUnit=days"                                       "PrintTimes=160"                                     
[19] "NumberOfSolutes=0"                                   "InitialCondition=1"                                  ";                                `here I want this`"
[22] "[Profile]                        `here I want this`" "NumberOfNodes=101"                                   "ProfileDepth=120"                                   
[25] "ObservationNodes=160"                                "GridVisible=160"                                     "SnapToGrid=160"                                     
[28] "ProfileWidth=160"                                    "LeftMargin=160"                                      "GridOrgX=160"                                       
[31] "GridOrgY=160"                                        "GridDX=160"                                          "GridDY=160"
```

## EDIT

In order to have the new output (as per OP request):

```
c(";","[Main]",text[1:18],";","[Profile]",text[19:length(text)])
```

Comment: Thanks. I improved the question. But I made it according to my choice. If you will improve it. It will be great.